# how to return a dictionary with template variables

Tags: python, dictionary, web, bottle, templating

I'm working with the python web framework [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) to generate html templates, and I want to pass a dictionary of template variables from the bottle server to the page. The [documentation](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf) says that can be done like this:

```
@route(’/hello/<name>’)
@view(’hello_template’)
def hello(name=’World’):
  return dict(name=name)
```

And the `@view` template should have access to `name`. I want to do the same thing with a dictionary of search results, simplified here:

```
@get('/search')
@view('search')
def search():
    // load results
    // return results
    results = {'1': {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2', 'param3': 'val3'},
               '2': {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2', 'param3': 'val3'}
              }
    return results
```

But I get this error:

`TypeError('template() keywords must be strings',)`

With this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3619, in wrapper
    return template(tpl_name, **tplvars)
TypeError: template() keywords must be strings
```

I could find similar questions but they all assumed that the params could be correctly passed, so I decided to ask. Thanks!

Comment: `template() keywords must be strings` Are your keywords is string?

Comment: I'm not sure--I'm not explicitly calling `template()` because I'm using the `@view` decorator instead

Comment: Try Convert string to int：`{1: {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2', 'param3': 'val3'},
               2: {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2', 'param3': 'val3'}
              }`

Comment: Can you please post your template, too?

Answer (score -1):

I realy don't understand how you get this error, but anyway your code equals to:

```
@route('/search')
def search():
    return template('search', **results)
```

`**` means that `template()` function must unpack `results` to keywords arguments. In other words this code :

```
@route('/')
def index()
    return template(template_name, **{'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

Absolutley equals this :

```
@route('/')
def index():
    return template(template_name, a=1, b=2)
```

And even equals this :

```
@route('/')
@view(template_name)
def index():
    return {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Now ask yourself how do you access variable named `1` or `2` ( you trying to use this variables ) in your template ?

In your case `template()` function unpacks `results` to keyword arguments.
If you want to pass `results` into template then use `return dict(results=results)`

But if you provide *real* code i think you'll get more detailed answer

Comment: but those are just strings used as keys in the dictionary, right? it shouldn't matter that they're numbers

Comment: i provided more detailed anwer, maybe it can help you